# No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA. However, when I try to retrieve data from my Repository, the following error is thrown:

```
Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.example.model.Pokemon$HibernateProxy$DuUnG9om[\"hibernateLazyInitializer\"])
```

Most of the "duplicates" I see have relationships, but my Pokemon class does not. Is there something that I am missing?

My Pokemon class is a simple POJO class:

```
package com.example.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Pokemon implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2228784815938588107L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
    private Double attack, defense, speed;

    public Pokemon() {

    }

    public Pokemon(int id, String name, double attack, double defense, double speed) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.attack = attack;
        this.defense = defense;
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Try adding getters and setters

Comment: @Aris_Kortex I indicated my getters and setters with a comment on the last line

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by using the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation.

```java
// package and imports

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer"})
@Entity
public class Pokemon implements Serializable {

// rest of code

}
```

Answer (score 1):

With your repository, when you retrieve one Pokemon use the method :

```
findById(id).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

What solved this issue for me was using
[jackson-datatype-hibernate5](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate)
and registering this module in objectmapper

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to add annotation to your fields, to map the column names with the fields
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

or did you put the annotation to the getters and setters?

Comment: I just added the @Column to each field, but the same error arises